# How to check if iOS OpenVPN Connect is installed?

Tags: ios, openvpn

We are developing an app that need to import the .ovpn file to OpenVPN Connect (iOS), but before the import, we need to check if the OpenVPN Connect (iOS) is installed on the iOS device. 
If it's not installed, we will prompt the user to install it first.

The question is : How to check if iOS OpenVPN Connect is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [OpenVPN Connect FAQ](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html):

**Q: I am a developer. How can I detect if OpenVPN Connect is installed?**

OpenVPN Connect 1.0.6 and higher installs the openvpn:// URL scheme and can be detected with the following code:

```
BOOL installed = [application canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"openvpn://"]];
```

**EDITED:** Unfortunately OpenVPN Connect in Appstore has version 1.0.5, seems that 1.0.6 was not released. So, no solution at the moment.